# Ember.js - setupController model no output

Tags: templates, properties, model, ember.js, controller

Ey guys,

I have a strange problem with one of my models:
The following code is responsible for getting the page model and all the new projects.

```
Bouwbedrijf.ProjectsOldRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Page.find(3);
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model)
  {
    controller.set('content', model);
    controller.set('projecten', App.OldProjects.find());
  },
  renderTemplate: function (){
    this.render();
    this.render('pagetitle', {into: 'projects', outlet: 'page-title'});
    this.render('oldprojectshowcase', {
    into: 'projects/old',
    outlet: 'projecten'
  });
 }
});
```

However if I loop through the controller.projecten within the template there is no propery output. I do see 3 li elements rendered but I can't seem to display the name of a project...

Here is the template code

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="oldprojectshowcase">
  <h3>Projects showcase</h3>
  <ul>
    {{#each project in projecten}}
     <li>{{project.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

To make things more clear for you guys I prepared a jsbin -> http://jsbin.com/Uqop/2/
Within this example there is a page Old projects which is displayin a showcase (sort of ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no relation between the problem and setupController.

The problem is you are trying to access a property which you have not defined in the model.
The property `name` is not defined in the `App.OldProjects` model.
Defining it does the trick.

```
App.OldProjects = DS.Model.extend({  
      title: DS.attr('string'),  
      project: DS.attr('string'),  
      name: DS.attr('string'),  
      img: DS.attr('string')  
  });
```

Corrections to your [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/IjId/3/edit).